# alternative to packaged unit downstairs

Tags: hvac

House built in 1922. Never had central air. Heated with hot water boiler and rads. 2 stories, 1569 sq ft. Salesman recommended split sys upstairs and packaged sys down. Only appx 22 inch clearance in crawl. Unable to put in ducts downstairs, so recommended ductless mini splits.(unacceptable to me). Is there an alternative?

Comment: There are 4 rooms downstairs. A dining and living with a 72 inch opening between them. A 30 inch opening leading to kitchen and a 60 sq ft bath off kitchen. Salesman recommended putting equipment in bath, dining and living. Not in kitchen. He said leave bathroom door open for kitchen ac at a cost of $5500 each! He said there was no room in the kitchen.

Answer (score 2):

Mini-splits have many advantages, so tossing them out wholesale is a somewhat puzzling response to a house with limited options for running ducts. If you don't like beige plastic boxes (who does, really?) there are several versions that are made to be visually unobtrusive, with the inside unit concealed in a picture frame, or a small inside unit that can be tucked in a ceiling, wall cavity or between the floor joists, either with a faceplate that is the register, or short ducts (a ducted mini-split, as opposed to ductless.)